# easiest way to load css and image file

Tags: django, pycharm

I am trying to load a web design into django project on pyCharm. I created the URL in url.py for first page and its corresponding function in the view.py. On running the project index.html file is loaded only without images and css files. I have been searching for the solution but I could not understand any of them. Some of those said, place your static files into 'static' in the root directory of project. But in my html code, I have referenced them as css/main.css. In this case I might have to change all the code. Is there some easiest way to load static files? Please guide me step by step.
Here is the structure of my files in the project:

```
MyProject/template:
css/"all css files
js/"all java script files"
image/"all images"
fonts/fonts
index.html and other html files![error log:][1]
```

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) and [more docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) . Your question is too broad.

Comment: yeah I checked it, applied too, but getting the same error, em gonna show errors in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. You need to create a `static` directory in your project root.
2. Specify the static directory in the django project settings.
3. Include the static files like css, js, image, fonts inside the `static` directory.
4. Change the static file's path in templates -- e.g. from `/css/bootstrap.min.css` to `{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}`

Comment: I did not understand the 4th one. you mean change the file's path in all html files?

Comment: yes...you can just do a quick replace from your IDE.